# Make substring() method ignore certain chars

Tags: java

I want to create an animation that builds a string by always appending one more char.
Like: `'H', 'He', 'Hel', 'Hell', 'Hello'`
For this, I've already created a simple method:

```
Collection<String> states = new ArrayList<>();
    String text = "§aTest §bTest2";
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
      states.add(text.substring(0, i));
    }
```

But as you can see, the string can also contain chars that are invisible for the user later (like §a and §b). Adding them to the animation states using the above method would look very strange because there are 2 states which have no visible change, which makes the animation glitch.
For example the user sees: `'', '', 'T', 'Te', 'Tes', 'Test', 'Test ', 'Test ', 'Test ', 'Test T'`

But they are important for the colours and may not be removed, because then there would be no colour.

So How can I ignore these chars when building the substrings without actually removing them from the string?

Comment: Instead of using `substring`, you could walk through it yourself with a simple for-loop where you increase a character count. Then simply do not increase it when you found such a special character.

Comment: Note that there might be better approaches to this than adding lots of string copies to a list. What about a custom `Iterator` whose `next` method spits out the next string for the animation. It then only needs to advance by one character. And then it is easy to simply advance it one further if it is a special character etc. Then you also do not have to hold all the string variants in memory, which does not scale at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your escape sequences are always `§` followed by a single character then you can skip over strings that have `§` as their last or second but last character:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
   String sub = text.substring(0, i);
   if ( sub.charAt(sub.length() - 1) == '§' || (sub.length() > 1 && sub.charAt(sub.length() - 2) == '§' )
      continue;
   states.add();
}
```

This will fail to pick up an escape sequence at the very end of `text` but it should be easy to handle that as well.